# OpenID Connect server. Generate access token based on 3-rd party token (social login)

Tags: asp.net-core, access-token, openiddict

I had implemented OpenID Connect server that generates access tokens for mobile client based on username/password using [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core).
My next goal was to provide ability to generate Access Token using 3-rd party tokens (social login for example), and I started from integration with Google token, but stuck as cannot find any samples/informations about how to do this.

The only one idea that I currently have is to make request to "/connect/token" endpoint and send Google token in "code" parameter, for example in  "google:" format, then override [OpenIdConnectServerProvider.DeserializeAuthorizationCode](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/blob/8578d38fb1122d0458842869927d5275e022846b/src/Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/OpenIdConnectServerProvider.cs#L621) method:

> Called when receiving an authorization code. An application may use this context to deserialize the code using a custom format and to skip the default logic using

So I have created own `CustomProvider` class based on `OpenIddictProvider`, registered it

```
services.AddOpenIddict<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext, int>()
    .Configure(builder =>
    { builder.Provider = new CustomProvider(sp.GetRequiredService<SignInService>()); }
```

and overridden the `DeserializeAuthorizationCode` method:

```
public override async Task DeserializeAuthorizationCode(DeserializeAuthorizationCodeContext context)
{
    string code = context.Request.Code;
    if (code.StartsWith("google:"))
    {
        string token = code.Replace("google:", "");
        var principal = new GoogleTokenValidator().ValidateToken(token, null).Result;
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, new AuthenticationProperties(), "Bearer");
        ticket.SetPresenters(context.Request.ClientId);
        context.Ticket = ticket;

        context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
        context.HandleResponse();

        await _signInService.Login(principal);

        return; 
    }
    else
    {
        base.DeserializeAuthorizationCode(context);
    }
}
```

where `GoogleTokenValidator` is a custom class for Google token handling (it makes call to Google User Information Endpoint and generate ClaimsPrincipal), based on "copy-pasted" code from [GoogleHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google/GoogleHandler.cs) class in aspnet/Security repo.

In general it is working with some additional hacks, but I have strong feeling that reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In general it is working with some additional hacks, but I have strong feeling that reinventing the wheel...

You're not only reinventing the wheel, but you're also implementing something totally non-standard that is not supported (at all) by OpenIddict.

Here's the approach I recommend (which is the one we use in the MVC server sample):

- The OAuth2/OpenID Connect client application redirects the user agent to your authorization controller (you can take a look at [this controller](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.Server/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs) for an example).
- OpenIddict will validate the authorization request and allow your controller to be invoked if it's fully valid.
- If the user is not already logged in, your authorization controller will redirect the user to the login endpoint, provided by `AccountController`. At this point, you're free to propose local authentication (e.g using a username/password couple) or Google authentication (you can use the Google authentication middleware for that). You can even offer 2-FA as part of this login process.
- Once the user is logged in (e.g after a registration process and/or an external authentication association), his/her browser is redirected back to the authorization endpoint, where a consent form indicating he/she's about to allow your JS app to access his personal data on his/her behalf is displayed.
- When the user allows your client application to access his data, the request is handled by your authorization controller, that calls `SignInAsync` to inform OpenIddict that an authorization code/access token should be returned to your application.

Comment: "will redirect the user to the login endpoint, " but what if I have mobile client, and don't want to open the browser? On mobile client there is the "embedded" social login forms, that returns access token on successful login in Google/facebook etc. And  I want just to exchange it with my own token.

Comment: `And I want just to exchange it with my own token.` > there's no way to support that in OpenIddict, as it's not standard. The IETF is currently working on a new draft (https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-token-exchange-05), but it will only work if both OpenIddict and external providers (here, Google) implement it.